# Prestashop webservices not filtering by date_upd

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm building a web api and i need the prestashop's products for it to work.

The thing is that there are over 80000 active products and that is really painfull.

So i'm trying to filter products that have been updated the last couple days in order to minimize the request load time.

the code i have so far is this

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://'.PS_WS_KEY.'@'.PS_WS_URL.'/api/products/?filter[date_upd]=[2021-01-01 00:00:00, 2021-04-07 00:00:00]&date=1&output_format=JSON',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);
```

The above cURL is returning an empty array. The other issue i have is that i can not filter specific fields when i get all products, i.e. id, name, price, description etc. Instead i get the id only.

Prestashop version 1.7.3, PHP 7.4

Comment: make sure this is not a PHP version issue , as PS 1.7.3 is only compatible with PHP 7.2 max.

Comment: I downgraded my php version to PHP 7.2.34 but still have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

To get all fields you must specify display=full, for example:

```
'https://'.PS_WS_KEY.'@'.PS_WS_URL.'/api/products/?display=full
```

When cURL responses empty erray, is status code 200?
Try:

```
'https://'.PS_WS_KEY.'@'.PS_WS_URL.'/api/products/?filter[date_upd]=[2021-01-01 00:00:00|2021-04-07 00:00:00]&date=1&output_format=JSON'
```

Comment: No i get a HTTP status of 400

Comment: Also display=full is not working at all.. i get nothing back no error neither empty array. Just blank

Comment: HTTP 400 is bad request, check URL is right, WS is enabled and method GET is allowed for product entity.

Comment: display=full should work, as Presta Doc says https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/getting-started/

Comment: Ok. I managed to set up a localhost prestashop site and allowed all permissions to products. So display=full is now working. But i can't figure out why filter[date_upd] is not

UPDATE: On postman is working like a charm. But no on a PHP script

Comment: If on postman works, WS is running properly. We need more info about script execution. ¿What code do you use for display=full test and filter test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231104/discussion-between-inemesis-and-fran-cerezo).

Comment: I can not, edit question adding as much info as possible and i read it later.